# WHOIS Domain Availability Search

Tags: php, search, whois, domain-name

I came upon the following domain check function and I can't seem to get it to work.

```
function domain_checker($domain){

$extension = explode(".",$domainname);  
$extension = $extension[1];  
switch($extension)  
{  
    case "com": $server = "whois.verisign-grs.com"; break;  
    case "net": $server = "whois.verisign-grs.com"; break;  
    case "org": $server = "whois.pir.org"; break;  
    case "info": $server = "whois.afilias.net"; break;  
    case "biz": $server = "whois.biz"; break;  
    case "name": $server = "whois.nic.name"; break;  
    default: return "Given Extension not supported"; exit();  
}  
// connecting to the whois server.  
$handle = fsockopen($server, 43);  
if (!$handle)  
    return false; // connectin failure   

//asking the server  
fwrite($handle, $domainname."\r\n");  

// getting response  
$response = '';  
while (!feof($handle))  
    $response .= fgets($handle, 1024);  

fclose($handle);  
//checking if domain is available or not  
if($extension=="com" || $extension=="net" || $extension=="name")  
{  
    if(stripos($response, 'No match') === FALSE )  
        return $domainname." is not Available!";  
    else  
        return $domainname. " is Available!";  
}  
else  
{  
    if(stripos($response, "NOT FOUND") === FALSE)  
        return $domainname. " is not Available!";  
    else  
        return $domainname. " is Available!";  
}
```

}

I keep getting the following error:

> Warning:  fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect
>   to whois.verisign-grs.com:43

Help appreciated!

Comment: From the error message, it is evident that `whois.verisign-grs.com` is not accepting connections on port `43`. You will probably have to find another whois server to pass your requests to.

Comment: It's not just the verisign server that gives the error, they all do. Is it that these servers stopped providing this information for free?

Comment: That is a possibility. Perhaps you could check with verisign's support to see if they have any whois servers with public access through an API or webservice.

Comment: Is it possible there's something about my server that's preventing me from doing a whois query? I found a demo of a script similar to this one and it worked fine, but when I added the function to my own site, it timed out...

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility as well. Are you able to launch a shell on your server and try connecting to the whois server?

Comment: If you can not connect to any server on port 43 it surely means there is either a firewqll on your host forbidding you do to that (silly, but it happens) or something on the network between your host and the Internet that forbids you to do that in the same way. So you will need to talk to your sysadmin/ISP to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

As @phpdev wrote: *From the error message, it is evident that whois.verisign-grs.com is not accepting connections on port 43. You will probably have to find another whois server to pass your requests to.*

I'll found a solution to verisign:

```
http://www.verisigninc.com/cgi-bin/whois?type=domain&eswhois_nic=google.com&whois_tld=com
```

Parameters: `eswhois_nic` is the domain name, and `whois_tld` is either *com* or *net*, based on domain
Then just do get request with curl or file_get_contents and voila ;)

Comment: I get a 500 Error with this URL. Is there a typo or something?

Comment: Okay, worked for me before, maybe i had something in session, updated my url :)

Comment: This url still isn't returning anything for me. It just times out after a while. Am I still missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that the link posted by kristian works.  You just need to set your COOKIE first.  It now has a captcha at their main site located here.

You would have to get your users to fill out the captcha there and store the result of the cookie.

http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/whois/index.xhtml